# C/C++ How is memory allocated by a system/stdlib call cleaned up?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Take this block of code for example:

```
int main() {

    tm* now;
    time_t time_ = time(0);
    now = localtime(&time_);

    int y = now->tm_year + 1900;

    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

We declare a pointer to a tm struct but we don't give it any memory. Then the localtime() function returns the address of a tm struct which we assign to our local variable 'now'.

Are we responsible for delete/dealloc()'ing that memory or is that memory actually on the stack somehow?

If localtime() created the memory on the stack, wouldn't the memory pointed to by 'now' become undefined (and therefore, unreliable) after localtime() returns? If localtime() created the memory on the heap, wouldn't we need to clean up that memory when we're finished with it?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime): "The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions."

Comment: The CRT has global state, errno, stdin, stdout, strtok() are other common examples.  You don't deallocate it yourself.  Some CRT implementations make it thread-local state, some provide thread-safe alternatives, ymmv.

Comment: @engf-010 The space usually comes after the comma, not before.

Answer (score 2):

It returns a pointer to a static internal tm, you don't need to do a clean up.

C++
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime

C
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime

Answer (score 1):

From Linux man page of `localtime`:

> The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

So there will not be a memory leak, no matter how many times you call localtime.

---

Now about how that memory is released when program terminates. In all operating systems you are likely to encounter (there are probably some obscure or ancient systems where this won't be true), when a process terminates, it's memory is released. In a modern normal OS with virtual memory, the memory space of a terminated process basically ceases to exist (how it maps to physical memory or swap file on disk is OS detail invisible to user space programs), so there's nothing left of the whole allocation.